# JavaFX: execute events in Sub- and in SuperClass

Tags: javafx, subclass, superclass, eventhandler

if I implement an onMouseClicked-EventHandler in a SuperClass like this:

```
public class SuperClass {
    public SuperClass() {
                
        setOnMouseClicked(new EventHandler<Event>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(Event event) {
                System.out.println("Super reacted");
            }
        });
    }
```

And I implement an onMouseClicked-EventHandler in a SubClass of SuperClass like this:

```
public class SubClass extends SuperClass{
    public SubClass() {
                
        setOnMouseClicked(new EventHandler<Event>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(Event event) {
                System.out.println("Sub reacted");
        });
    }
}
```

After clicking on a instance of SubClass the result in the console will be "Sub reacted". So the SuperClass does not notice the event.

How can I forward the event in a way, that all super classes react too? I thought of manually firing an event in the sub class, but it dosnt work.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: why do you want different handlers on different levels of the _class_ hierachie? What do you really want to achieve (feels like a xy-question)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There exists two ways to register with widgets in JavaFX:

- `setOnMouseClicked` (all the `setOn...` methods). The handler associated with `setOnMouseClicked` is unique: in your case the sub-class registration replaces the registration made in the super class.
- `addEventHandler` (or `AddEventFilter`). In this case you can have multiple handlers that register with the same widget. These methods take as arguments: the type of event you want to listen; a instance of the type `EventHandler<>` that you can write as a callback or an anonymous class.
  In your case:

```
addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_CLICKED, evt -> {
 // ... 
});
```

or using an anonymous class:

```
addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_CLICKED, new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
   @Override
   public void handle(final MouseEvent evt) {
   }
});
```

Where `evt` is the triggered mouse click event.

The use of `addEventHandler` should fix your issue.